# Is Knockback.js production ready?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, knockout.js, knockback.js

I've used Backbone.js, I've learned about Knockout.js; however, now I found out about Knockback.js. It is supposed to get the best out of the other two tried& proven frameworks.
Do you have any experience with Knockback in production? I'm wary to use it since it doesn't seem to be mature enough.

Comment: Both exist: http://kmalakoff.github.com/knockback/

Comment: The fact that knockout will be included in MVC4 would suggest it is reaching maturity and has a strong level of momentum behind it.

Comment: @MarkRobinson - I think Mihai was referring to Knock**back**. KO is clearly prod ready and so is Backbone but I am not sure about KB.

Comment: @madcapnmckay - D'oh! Must stop skim reading questions! Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if this changed at all.

Comment: I wonder why they don't call it *boneout*.js?

Comment: @Faust ... or *backout.js*? Guess *knockout.js* just sounds that much more awesome...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't use it yet.  It's hard enough to get corporate buy in on knockoutJS.

I guess it all has to do with the size of your company, the willingness to support alpha / beta / volatile open source projects.

It is the nature of the beast, this bleeding edge of innovation.  Skating that thin ice of unsuportability.

Comment: FWIW, asp.net MVC 4 comes pre-loaded with Knockout.JS.  And from what I know of it's creator Steve Sanderson, I don't see a problem with using it.  Anyway, the success of production systems has more to do with the quality of the developer.  I've seen people mess up production apps with Jquery.

Comment: Don't get me wrong.  It's not impossible to get a large organization to adopt.  I work in a $3b/yr organization and am more than half way through a 100% knockoutJS single page app.

Comment: I totally hear where you're coming from as well.  The additional requirement with any large organization is supportability.  JQuery is well documented and widely accepted.  Therefore it is easily supportable ( think 5 years later ).  We've made the jump into knockoutJS hoping it will be a sustainable solution.  So the question is "is knockBack going to be a long term supportable solution?"

Answer (score 32):

I've been using Knockback on a large multi-module project with good results.  The docs and examples are unnecessarily complex, so I wrote a blog describing Knockback with some very simple examples and a JSFiddle to get you started.

http://www.geekdave.com/?p=79

Feedback is most welcome!

Comment: just curious, how many people are working on the 'large multi-module project' that you mentioned?

i agree with you about the docs. I've found all 3 (bb, ko, kb) to have spotty documentation

Comment: also, your backbone.subroute plugin is boss

Comment: @CoryDanielson: I manage a team of five engineers, but we're building the common infrastructure that will be used my dozens more engineers who will build actual modules.  Also, despite all the research that went into supporting KO/KB, we've just switched to using Backbone.ModelBinder (https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder) which has proven to be faster, and easier-to-understand.  I'd strongly recommend it.  Glad you're enjoying the subroute plugin!  I just released v0.2 with some important bug fixes and new features.  Check it out! https://github.com/ModelN/backbone.subroute

Comment: thanks for the update. At a glance, ModelBinder looks very useful. The team that I work on also decided to back away from Knockback and stick with Backbone... mostly due to the overhead in learning about 3 different libraries, higher potential for memory leaks, and because the community & support for backbone is unparalleled. Personally, I think Knockback is an awesome library and would be very fun to use on personal projects... I was pretty excited with how quickly i was able to get things working with it...

Comment: The bloat of dependencies that comes with Knockback is pretty rough though, especially on mobile. jQuery, underscore, Backbone, Knockout, Knockback... it's quite a fat stack... for all the functionality that it provides, Ember.js may be more beneficial to look into.

Comment: @CoryDanielson : I'm excited to see where Ember.js goes in the future, but for now it doesn't quite seem production ready, based on the size of the community, # of plugins available, documentation, etc.  It does feel a bit like building a Frankenstein monster, sometimes, stitching together all these libraries.  But such is the life of a JS architect these days!