# The simplest example of Knockback js working with a RESTful webservice such as ServiceStack?

Tags: backbone.js, knockout.js, servicestack, knockback.js

I am looking for a VERY simple example that shows wiring up Knockback code to a backbone model that connects via RESTful service.  I am using ServiceStack|c# backend.  All of the links below are too complicated and use localStore rather than a RESTful service via url.  I also prefer to see examples in Javascript not CoffeeScript.

My example url is something like **localhost/entities** where hitting this will cause the RESTful webservice to return all of the entities.  Hitting it with **localhost/entity/1** would return the entity with an Id of 1.

_http://kmalakoff.github.com/knockback/index.html

_https://github.com/kmalakoff/knockback-reference-app/

_https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc

The following is the example from knockback tutorial on the first link:

```
Models, Collection, ViewModel, and Bindings:
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.3.3
var model, view_model;

model = new Backbone.Model({
  first_name: "Planet",
  last_name: "Earth"
});

view_model = kb.viewModel(model);

view_model.full_name = ko.computed((function() {
  return "" + (this.first_name()) + " " + (this.last_name());
}), view_model);

ko.applyBindings(view_model, $('#kb_view_model_computed')[0]);
```

But there is no mention of how you would wire the backbone model up to your RESTful webservice.

There are examples of how do this via Backbone but I am uncertain as to how things change when using Knockback.

The following links were found, but not helpful:

_http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992431/using-knockoutjs-backbone-together

_http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704220/is-knockback-js-production-ready

_http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434203/defining-models-on-server-side-when-using-mvvm-with-knockout-js

Thanks in advance for any assistance provided.  Btw you don't want hyperlinks you get underscores...  ;)

Comment: You can use [knockback.js](http://kmalakoff.github.com/knockback)

Answer (score 7):

With much help and support from Kevin Malakoff from the great [Knockback](http://kmalakoff.github.com/knockback/) project I was able to get a small example working!  I used the [ServiceStack Backbone Todos](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/Backbone.Todos/Global.asax.cs) project as a starting point.

**c# file:** *Global.asax.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;

using ServiceStack.Redis;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;
using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonService : RestServiceBase<Person>
    {
        public static Person kevin = new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "Kevin", LastName = "Malakoff" };
        public static Person scott = new Person { Id = 2, FirstName = "Scott", LastName = "Idler" };
        public static List<Person> people = new List<Person> { kevin, scott };

        public override object OnGet(Person person)
        {
            if (person.Id != default(int))
                return people[person.Id-1];
            return people;
        }

        public override object OnPost(Person person)
        {
            return base.OnPost(person);
        }

        public override object OnPut(Person person)
        {
            return OnPost(person);
        }

        public override object OnDelete(Person person)
        {
            return base.OnDelete(person);
        }
    }

    public class AppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public AppHost() : base("MyApp", typeof(PersonService).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;
            Routes
              .Add<Person>("/persons")
              .Add<Person>("/persons/{Id}");
        }
    }

    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new AppHost().Init();
        }
    }
}
```

**html file:** *default.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>MyApp2</title>
    <script>window.JSON || document.write('<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockback-full-stack-0.16.1.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="myapp.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  </head>
<body>
    <div id="myapp">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>MyApp</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div id='kb_observable'>
                <p>First name: <input class='text' data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
                <p>Last name: <input class='input-small pull-right' data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
                <p>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span>!</p>
            </div>
            <div id="kb_collection_observable">
                <div data-bind="if: persons">
                    <span>Has Persons</span>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="foreach: persons">
                    <p>First name: <input class='text' data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
                    <p>Last name: <input class='input-small pull-right' data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**javascript file:** *myapp.js*

> $(function() {
>
> ```
> //model
> var PersonModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ urlRoot: '/MyApp/persons' });
> var model = new PersonModel({ id: 1 });
> model.fetch();
>
> //viewmodel
> var PersonViewModel = function (person) {
>
>     this.firstName = kb.observable(person, 'firstName');
>     this.lastName = kb.observable(person, 'lastName');
>     this.fullName = ko.computed((function () {
>         return "" + (this.firstName()) + " " + (this.lastName());
>     }), this);
> };
> var personViewModel = new PersonViewModel(model);
>
> //binding
> ko.applyBindings(personViewModel, $('#kb_observable')[0]);
>
> //model
> var PersonsModel = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: PersonModel, url: '/MyApp/persons' });
> var personsModel = new PersonsModel();
> personsModel.fetch();
>
> //viewmodel
> var PersonsViewModel = function (persons) {
>     this.persons = kb.collectionObservable(persons)
> };
> var personsViewModel = new PersonsViewModel(personsModel);
>
> //binding
> ko.applyBindings(personsViewModel, $('#kb_collection_observable')[0]); });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I put together a very simple example.  It assumes you already know how to use backbone and knockout so this just gives a quick example of how they can be used together

http://coder2.blogspot.com/2013/02/backbonejs-and-knockoutjs.html